# Table ranking through SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I am trying to rank an income/block group table with incomes between 0-10 as 1, between 11-20 as 2 and so on. I do not understand the issue with my query.

[Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfmQD.jpg)

[The table I am working with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRnjX.jpg)

Thanks.

Comment: obviously it says 23.something.. that means it's not INT .. change it to float or whatever data type for double

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557

Answer (score 0):

change int to float/double/real number

23.75 is not an integer